# How to use JDBC connector in mac to connect mssql

Tags: osx-lion

I am trying to use the JDBC connector to connect to mssql, how to use in Xcode 4.2, or in command prompt, Right now I am using OSX 10.7.3
IS there any sample example is there.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial have detailed explanation: http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html. The site is just awesome and has many other great tutorials!

In short:

```java
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");
statement = connect.createStatement();
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename");
```

Is this what you need?